# Flink timer not triggered

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Flink job I have a `KeyedProcessFunction`.

I have implemented a watermark strategy

```
val wmStrategy: WatermarkStrategy<MyInput> =
        WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps<MyInput>()
            .withTimestampAssigner { event: MyInput, _: Long -> event.getTimestampEvent() }
```

and then i apply it to my source data:

```
mysource.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(wmStrategy)
```

When `processElement` is called a timer may be registered `ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(timerWakeUpInstant.toEpochMilli())` and after that the `ValueState` is updated. Update is successful.

The next time `processElement` is called, `valueState.value()` returns `null` instead of the last updated value.
No `clear()` is called explicitly on the value state.
The timer is never triggered.

At the moment, I'm testing in a 'clean' environment, reading from a text file with data referring to only a key, and with `parallelism = 1` running into my IDE.

Can you help me? Why the state is nullified? And why timer is not triggered?

Comment: If the ValueState is null it might be that you received an element with a different key than before. Remember that timers are keyed too

Comment: @emilio as event time goes on won’t timer trigger anyway?

Comment: Yes as long as the event time advances registered timer continue to fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried myself: `OnTimer` is not called until the `Function` that has registered the timer receives a message that advences the watermark.

> With event-time timers, the onTimer(...) method is called when the current watermark is advanced up to or beyond the timestamp of the time

The "current" watermark actually refers to the operator, and not the job. This was misleading for me, as i thought it was centralized.

Looking at some [code sample](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/testing/) in the documentation we can find a useful comment that may give us a hint:

> //trigger event time timers by advancing the event time of the operator with a watermark